# What is the cardinality of the following set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardinality of the following set: $\{f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{a+b\sqrt[3]4\ | a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}\}$?

Let $S = \{f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{a+b\sqrt[3]4\ | a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}\}$.

I already show that $\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\{0,1\}\} \subset S$, then $|S| \ge |\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\{0,1\}\}| = 2^c$, and I need to show the rest of the part i.e.: $|S| \le 2^c$, then to conclude that the cardinality of the set $S$ is $2^c$.  (please correct me if this part is wrong)

But I get stuck, I don't know how to show that $|S| \le 2^c$. Can you please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume $R$ and $Q$ are supposed to be $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Would you be more comfortable if $\{\,a+b\sqrt[3]4\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\,\}$ were replaced with $\Bbb N$?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the set of functins from $\mathbb{R}$ which has size $2^{\aleph_0}= \mathfrak{c}$ to a countable set (as $|\mathbb{Q}^2| = \aleph_0$) which by definition has size $(\aleph_0)^{2^{\aleph_0}} = 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ by standard cardinal arithmetic : $$ 2^\mathfrak{c} \le \aleph_0^{\mathfrak{c}} \le (2^\mathfrak{c})^\mathfrak{c} = 2^\mathfrak{c}$$

Comment: Can you find an one to one function map to show that the cardinality of the set S is less than or equal to $2^c$. Since we haven't learned cardinal arithmetic yet...

Comment: You'll need axiom of choice for that, in order to use a bijection between $\mathfrak c \times \mathfrak c$ and $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net well for $\mathfrak{c}$ we can show it without AC: use the representation as sequences of natural numbers that can be interleaved.